# Zoom 3D numpy array image

Tags: python, numpy, zooming, data-augmentation

Imagine we have an (x, y, z) numpy array and we want to zoom it.

If we use [cipy.ndimage.zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) the image will be reshaped... I need to zoom the image by maintaining the original shape. Is there any option better than clipping out or zero-padding?

In cases where the size of the image increases it is wasteful to interpolate pixels that are only going to get clipped off at the edges anyway.

If there is no other way without clipping out or zero-padding, how can I do it?

I have 3D volume of size (240, 240, 155). So If I use a factor of 2 I get a volume of size (480, 480, 310)... now I need to middle crop it to (240, 240, 155) again.

Also, in case the zoom factor is 0.5 and we need to zero-pad, how should it be done?

Comment: Nope, you'll need to identify the subregion that will survive and zoom that.  That is, if you're zooming by 3, you'd extract the center square.

Comment: Okay, so there is no option other than clipping out or zero-padding, right?

Comment: Like what?  The library doesn't know what you want.  If you do an up zoom, it is naturally going to assume you want ALL of those pixels.  You have an exception case, so you have to tell it what you want.

Comment: I have a 3D volume (240, 240, 155). I need to make zoom in or zoom out but without reshaping. Imagine I do a zoom with factor 2... I get a volume of size (480, 480, 310), but now I need to slice/crop it to (240, 240, 155).

Comment: Right.  We know that.   But only YOU know WHICH quarter of the cube you want to keep.  THAT'S the point.  Do you want the upper left?  Do you want the middle?

Comment: I need the middle one :)

Comment: Then you extract the middle of YOUR cube, and zoom that.

Comment: That's smart!! what if I have a zoom factor of 0.5 and need to zero-pad?

Comment: With numpy, you create `np.zeroes` of the size you want, and copy the smaller subcube to the middle.

Comment: I have already done the zero padding successfully with np.pad! Now I just need a way to extract a cube from the middle of the volume

Comment: numpy makes that easy.  `cube[60:180,60:180,40:118]`.

Comment: Perfect! So I just need to find the coordinates of the middle. Thank you so much man!